# custom labels for xAxis on Scatter Chart using Google API

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

I'm new to the google-api, and i'm trying to whip together a quick chart.

**What I have**

```
 10 |        .     .
    |      .
  5 |  .         .
    |  .
  0 |_______________
       1    2    3    4
```

**What I want**

```
 10 |        .     .
    |      .
  5 |  .         .
    |  .
  0 |_______________
       1pm  2pm  3pm  4pm
```

Doing this is a piece of cake using a Line Chart; All that is required is for you to make the first column of the DataTable a string. However a Scatter Chart forces you to use a 'number' for the first column.

So how can I write custom labels for the xAxis using Google API + Charts

[Scatter Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/GTtDQ/1/)

[Line Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/GTtDQ/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`chx1`](http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=s&chd=t:12,87,75,41,23,96,68,71,34,9%7C98,60,27,34,56,79,58,74,18,76%7C84,23,69,81,47,94,60,93,64,54&chxt=x,y&chs=400x200&chxl=0:%7C12PM%7C1PM%7C2PM%7C3PM%7C4PM%7C5PM%7CF%7CG)?

```
cht=s
chd=t:12,87,75,41,23,96,68,71,34,9
    98,60,27,34,56,79,58,74,18,76
    84,23,69,81,47,94,60,93,64,54
chxt=x,y
chs=400x200
chxl=0:|12PM|1PM|2PM|3PM|4PM|5PM|F|G
```

[Documentation here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/scatter_charts.html#gcharts_axis_styles_labels)

[image]

You could also use tools such as:

http://imagecharteditor.appspot.com/

or even

https://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_playground.html